# Python 2D Interpolation onto Random Points

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have an interpolation problem that should be simple but I can't for the life of me get scipy to handle correctly.  I want to interpolate in 2D from regularly sampled points onto irregularly spaced points (in particular, I have a profile measured on a sphere that's sampled on a grid in theta and phi, that I want to project into a different pixellization of the sphere).  Creating the interpolator (using scipy.interpolate.interp2d) goes fine, but there doesn't seem to be any way to evaluate it for a list of points that aren't on a grid.  In particular, if func2d is the output of interpolate2d, then I want

```
    zi=func2d(xi,yi)
```

to return something that's a 1-d array rather than a 2-d array with dimensions (len(xi),len(yi)).

The documentation says

```
     |      Returns
     |      -------
     |      z : 2D array with shape (len(y), len(x))
     |          The interpolated values.
```

so perhaps it's impossible?  I could obviously loop over points, but that just seems primitive.  This seems like such a common use case that there must be a simple solution, but for the life of me I can't find one.  Does anyone have a suggestion?  It would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This works - thanks!  To the person who asked for an example, something like x=np.linspace(...), y=np.linspace(...), z=function(np.meshgrid(x,y)), ifun=RegularGridInterpolator((x,y),z,...) gets the interpolating function, then you can call ifun((xx,yy)) to get interpolated values, where xx and yy can be vectors.